# JIRA and Confluence both running with AJP protocol - How to?

Tags: apache, tomcat, jira, confluence, ajp

I have a server running the following apps:

- JIRA
- Confluence

Each application has its own subdomain.

- jira.thelavender.net
- wiki.thelavender.net

I have managed to get JIRA working with its subdomain by configuring my VirtualHost as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jira.thelavender.net

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Block
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /jira http://thelavender.net:8080/jira
    ProxyPassReverse /jira http://thelavender.net:8080/jira

    # JIRA AJP Proxy Configuration:
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyRequests           Off
    ProxyPass               /       ajp://thelavender.net:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse        /       ajp://thelavender.net:8009/
</VirtualHost>
```

I then copied this configuration, renamed it to confluence.conf, edited the information so it matches that of Confluence. Made sure there was a correct symlink to the sites-enabled directory.

Restarted Apache
Restarted Confluence

I can still get to Confluence by going to `thelavender.net/wiki` but whenever I goto `wiki.thelavender.net` JIRA ends up loading.

The only thing special I had to do to my JIRA / Tomcat `server.xml` was uncomment one line:

`<Connector port="8009" redirectPort="8443" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>`

This line does not exist in the JIRA / Tomcat `server.xml`  Looking at Atlassian documentation, there is no documentation that I have found that specifically talks about configuring Confluence for use with AJP. Documentation for JIRA and AJP exists however.

I thought perhaps adding" `<Connector port="8009" redirectPort="8443" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>` to my JIRA `server.xml` would help. Confluence still starts up with no issue but I am still getting the JIRA login page.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Looking at some other sites, it looked like when people have multiple apps running, they run them on different ports for their AJP config?

JIRA is configured as `8009`. Based on that I configured Confluence for `8109`. Now when I attempt to load `wiki.thelavender.net` I get a blank page.

Tailing the `other_vhosts_access.log` I seem to be getting an HTTP 404 error now: `GET / HTTP/1.1" 404`. The entire line is:

`wiki.thelavender.net:80 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [23/Jul/2016:15:23:01 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 170 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13F69 Safari/601.1"`

**FINAL UPDATE**

Ok so I went in and edited my virtual host file.

I changed:

```
ProxyPass               /       ajp://thelavender.net:8109/
ProxyPassReverse        /       ajp://thelavender.net:8109/
```

to

```
ProxyPass               /       ajp://thelavender.net:8109/wiki
ProxyPassReverse        /       ajp://thelavender.net:8109/wiki
```

Restarted Confluence and now I can get to it by going to `wiki.thelavender.net`

**Of course, everything is served behind /wiki but it works. Is there a specific reason I get a 404 error when its not using `/wiki`?**

Answer (score 0):

Your confluence's context path is set to /wiki, so you have to access it via an url that ends with /wiki.

You're not serving anything at /, so that returns a 404 (not found).

If you don't want to use /wiki as your context path, then [this KB article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-change-the-confluence-context-path-707985922.html) explains how you can update it.